# Retornar todos os valores de uma matriz com condições

Tags: microsoft-excel

Estou tentando pegar uma lista de produtos a partir de 2 valores no excel.
Vi [neste tutorial](http://www.excelnaweb.com.br/2014/03/funcao-procv-como-retornar-todos-resultados.html) que posso fazer uma formula da seguinte maneira:

```
={SEERRO(ÍNDICE($A$6:$B$15;MENOR(SE($A$6:$A$15=$E$5;LIN($A$6:$A$15)-5);LIN(A1));2);"")}
```

Essa é a solução se eu fosse pesquisar a partir de um valor, mas preciso de usar dois valores para a pesquisa, então coloquei outro `SE()` para fazer isso (Estou usando o Office 2010 e não tenho o `SES()`)
Minha função é a seguinte:

```
={SEERRO(ÍNDICE('Materiais Usados'!$A$3:$G$27;MENOR(SE('Materiais Usados'!$A$3:$G$27=$A$26;SE('Materiais Usados'!$A$3:$G$27=$B$1;LIN('Materiais Usados'!$A$3:$G$27)-2));LIN(A1));1);"")}
```

Ela não estava funcionando, entao quando depurei percebi que ele me dava o erro `#NÚM!` pelo seguinte motivo: Quando ele entra no segundo `SE()` ele perde a informação dos numeros do `SE()` anterior e os transformam em FALSE. Então como corrijo isso? Existe outra formula que eu possa usar para isso? Grato.

Answer (score 1):

O problema pode ser resolvido assim (de uma forma não convencional):

Digamos que a coluna "A" contenha o "Valor 1" que é o código do cliente e a coluna "B" o "Valor 2" que é o código do produto, crie na coluna "C" o "Valor 3" com o número da linha + 1 da ocorrência deste cliente para este produto, por exemplo:

**Linha 5 coluna A, "Valor 1" = 15** (cliente 15)

**Linha 5 coluna B, "Valor 2" = 987** (produto 987)

**Linha 5 coluna C, "Valor 3" = 6** (número da linha + 1, na célula: LIN()+1)

Na tabela de resultados crie uma coluna adicional para registrar a linha inicial da próxima busca para o mesmo cliente, por exemplo:

```
Código do Cliente: 15

Produto   Linha inicial
          2
987       6
1021      197
1533      202
-         -
-         -
-         -
-         -
```

Observe que a primeira célula da linha da coluna "Produto" está em branco, e assim deve permanecer, mas a respectiva célula ao lado da coluna "Linha inicial" está com o valor 2, isso quer dizer que toda busca irá iniciar a partir da segunda linha (supondo que a linha 1 tenha o cabeçalho).

Assim, a primeira fórmula deve iniciar a busca "somente para o mesmo código de cliente (15)" a partir da linha imediatamente superior pelo valor da célula da coluna "Linha inicial", por exemplo, a primeira busca iniciará a partir da linha 2 e este cliente (15) será encontrado na linha 5 com o respectivo código de produto 987, então será registrado o número da próxima linha "a iniciar a nova busca", a linha 6 (5 + 1).

Na fórmula da próxima linha para a busca "somente para o mesmo código do cliente", deverá ser iniciada a partir da linha 6 - que será pega da  coluna "Linha inicial" da linha superior que apresentou a primeira ocorrência - e resultará na próxima ocorrência na linha 196 com o produto 1021, que por sua vez indicará a próxima linha a iniciar a busca, a 197 (196 + 1), e assim deve ser feito sucessivamente.

A fórmula deve considerar que, se não houver ocorrência (cliente não encontrado a partir da linha inicial da respectiva linha do momento da busca, o resultado será "branco" (aspas duplas, por exemplo) ou como apresentado "um traço" ("-").

Já apliquei este tipo de solução para casos similares.

Comment: OI @Lucas, a resposta te serviu de alguma forma? Se sim, por favor, marque a resposta no "check" abaixo da pontuação de votação da resposta, grato.